# Book on ASP .NET MVC & Multi-tier architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

Do you know any books that explain multi tier architecture (like separation of application server from web server, benefits, drawbacks etc.) ? It would be nice if the book included samples how to fit ASP .NET MVC 3.0 into it, but good comprehensive book on multitier architecture will suffice.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is pretty good:

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-Design-Patterns-Millett/dp/0470292784](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470292784)

Comment: Shares best practice tools for ASP.NET such as AutoMapper, NHibernate, StructureMap, Entity Framework, and Castle MonoRail & Shows how Fowler's enterprise patterns fit into an enterprise-level ASP.NET site - looks preety good :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend [Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202) by Jimmy Nilsson. It doesn't cover Asp.Net MVC 3 nor does it focus on splitting your app across multiple servers. What it does focus on though is the architecture and design patterns needed to make that setup clean, maintainable, and sustainable. It covers topics like setting up repositories and services, using dependency injection to decouple those services from your web layer, performing test driven development, and of course the whole concept of domain driven design (model-centric development).

It's a fantastic read and a lot easier to consume (in my opinion) than Eric Evans's book. Eric Evans, for all of his genius, is a bit dry for me. Nilsson is a funny guy and really breathes excitement into what *should* be a dry topic. You'll put the book down energized and more importantly, a lot more equipt to deal with multi-tier (or any, for that matter) development.

I have given the book away to a number of colleagues and former professors, all of whom have reported back that it was a fantastic read. I highly recommend it to any professional developer regardless of what langauge or framework they are currently on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Which Eric Evans's book you're refering to?

Comment: @dragonfly http://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1321906675&sr=8-1

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all these other fine books, I've heard good things about [Microsoft® .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X).

Comment: This book has a good chapter on MVC and how to approach MVC nowadays in the context of ASP.NET MVC rather than in the way it was originally described 20+ years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I good choice would be Pattern of [Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa) (martin flower) which will help you to understand everything around application architecture design(layering,patterns,ecc).I think is more important learn the concepts around application design then the technology you will use to implement it. Asp.net MVC is usually the TOP layer of your stack(Front End) which does not tell you about the lower layers (Domain/DAL,BL,etc)

Comment: Thanks! It's extremely good book - one of my favourites - and I always keep it on my desk. However, I need title with more general overview on how to connect pieces of the puzzle. That book is still more about design patterns and implementation details to me.